# Convert Makefile/Bash list to Python list

Tags: python, makefile

With the following Makefile file:

```
datetime := $(shell date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
    
target := $(shell echo $$TARGET)

dothis:
    @python -c "import shutil ; \
                from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns; \
                shutil.copytree('$(target)', 'target-$(datetime)', ignore=ignore_patterns('1', '2', '3')); \
                "
        
dothat:
    @python -c "import shutil ; \
                from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns; \
                shutil.copytree('$(target)', 'target-$(datetime)', ignore=ignore_patterns('1', '2', '3')); \
                print('done')"
```

I can

```
$ TARGET=folder1 make dothis
```

and

```
$ TARGET=folder2 make dothat
```

Where `dothis` executes a Pyhton script and `dothat` executes another Python script, `$target` comes from the command line and is replaced in the Python script.

In both cases I pass a list of `ignore_patterns`, since the list is the same for `dothis` and `dothat` I'm thinking to define it only once on the Makefile and pass it in the Python script as a variable, as I do for `datetime`.

How can I convert from a Bash/Makefile list to a Python list?

I tried the following, though it does not work.

```
datetime := $(shell date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
    
target := $(shell echo $$TARGET)
                
list := $(1 2 3)

dothis:
    @python -c "import shutil ; \
                from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns; \
                shutil.copytree('$(target)', 'target-$(datetime)', ignore=ignore_patterns($(list))); \
                "
        
dothat:
    @python -c "import shutil ; \
                from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns; \
                shutil.copytree('$(target)', 'target-$(datetime)', ignore=ignore_patterns($(list))); \
                print('done')"
```

Comment: Have you tried `sys.argv` and passing in the list as arguments to the script?

Comment: Actually I would like to have the list in the script not having to pass it

Answer (score 1):

`make` doesn't have lists, or even numbers. It just has strings.  But that should be sufficient for your purposes.

Before we get to that, however, several comments on your example code:

- if your only purpose for setting the `TARGET` environment variable is to be able to transfer its value to the makefile's `target` macro, then you're taking inspiration from [Rube Goldberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg).  You can set `make` macros *directly* in the command line -- the assignments just have to appear as arguments to `make`:

  ```
   make target=folder1 dothis
  ```

  or

  ```
   make dothat target=folder2
  ```
- In a makefile, the `$()` syntax requests expansion of a macro or (GNU make only) of a function call.  `$(1 2 3)` does not express either of those, because `1 2 3` is not a valid variable name, and `1` is not the name of any built-in function.  You don't need special delimiters around the literal text of a `make` macro's value.
- You don't need or especially want a Python list for an argument to `shutil.ignore_patterns()`.  All you need is a comma-separated sequence of arguments.  If you plan to present globs then you'll need to provide appropriate Python quoting, but you don't need any special quoting for `make`.
- When you have a make rule whose recipe does not actually create the target (as a file), then it's usually a good idea to alert `make` to that by designating the targets of such rules as prerequisites of the special target `.PHONY`.  That's a GNU-ism, but it should be harmless in `make`s that don't understand it, and you're already relying on GNU-specific features anyway.

Something like this should work:

```
datetime := $(shell date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)

# Default to the current working directory; can be overridden on the command line:
target := .

# The arguments to to shutil.ignore_patterns, which are text to `make`:
ignore := 1, 2, 3

dothis:
    @python -c "import shutil ; \
                from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns; \
                shutil.copytree('$(target)', 'target-$(datetime)', ignore=ignore_patterns($(ignore)))"
        
dothat:
    @python -c "import shutil ; \
                from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns; \
                shutil.copytree('$(target)', 'target-$(datetime)', ignore=ignore_patterns($(ignore))); \
                print('done')"

.PHONY: dothis dothat
```

HOWEVER, for this particular case, I would go farther.  Your two Python scripts are identical except for whether they include the `print('done')` statement.  Why repeat all that?  There are several ways you could avoid the repetition, but this is among the simpler ones:

```
datetime := $(shell date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)

# Default to the current working directory; can be overridden on the command line:
target := .

# The arguments to to shutil.ignore_patterns, which are text to `make`:
ignore := 1, 2, 3

dothis:
    @python -c "import shutil ; \
                from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns; \
                shutil.copytree('$(target)', 'target-$(datetime)', ignore=ignore_patterns($(ignore)))"

# First, build target dothis, then print "done":
dothat: dothis
    echo done

.PHONY: dothis dothat
```

Comment: Why do you call `target` a macro? May I call it a variable?

Comment: @KcFnMi, "macro" is the terminology used by POSIX.  "Variable" is a commonly used alternative.  You may use either, but the present case is actually illustrative if you look instead at the `ignore` macro / variable.  Making it expand to `1, 2, 3`, as I have suggested, that being a fragment of a larger expression in a different language, is rather more macro-like, and rather less like variable-like, at least to me.